# Python provides different dtypes for same column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to provide a minimal example soon, but in the meantime: How is it possible, that column "Home Points" is type object and int64 simultaniously? Any hint? Is this a pandas bug?

```
>>>print(df[["Home Team", "Away Team", "Home Points", "Away Points"]].dtypes)
>>>print()
>>>print(df["Home Points"].describe())
>>>print()
>>>df['Home Points'].unique()

Home Team      object
Away Team      object
Home Points    object
Away Points    object
dtype: object

count     8754
unique       3
top          3
freq      3801
Name: Home Points, dtype: int64

array([3, 1, 0], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Can you share the data as well ? for better insights

Comment: Not yet. I a little more complicated because I scrape an preprocess the data. And if you would test just with read_csv(...) it could falsify the test through import data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not. In your first `info()` you are describing the column within the dataframe, whereas in the output of

```
df['Home Point'].describe()
```

You are evaluating the output of said method, which per its [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html):

> Returns
> Series or DataFrame
> Summary statistics of the Series or Dataframe provided.

Said output is what's being evaluated and considered as `int`, not the source column for the method. Therefore, it's a completely different object for Python, it just happens that the series has the same name as the column in the original dataframe.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thanks.